# Massive view spike on a single question?

Tags: discussion, support

[How to avoid drinking vodka?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/how-to-avoid-drinking-vodka)

This question was only asked yesterday but as of time of writing, it'd received 2509 views - about 6 times that of any other question on Travel.SE (that I know of).  In theory there's nothing wrong with that, views are good, I'm just curious as to whether anyone can come up with a reason why it's spiked so much?

Comment: not really a bug, we are counting stuff just the way we are supposed to :)

Comment: yeah this was back in October, when our traffic was really low, so to suddenly see such a spike was a question.  We worked it out - I think it was Jeff Atwood at the time who had tweeted it.

Comment: see other answers below from back then.

Comment: @JeffAtwood is a one man promotional army when it comes to twitter :)

Comment: Agreed, fantastic when he tweets one of ours.  Since you've tagged him in this, perhaps he'll tweet another... c'mon Jeff, pick one of the fun ones ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And just found out the answer to my own question.

[It's kinda gone 'viral' on twitter!](https://twitter.com/#!/search/how%20to%20avoid%20drinking%20vodka)

Which is all good for Travel.SE. Yay!

Comment: FYI, mods can see stats. Go to mod > analytics.

Comment: Yeah, I'd had a look there, but all it did was confirm that views had spiked.  In hindsight I could have broken down the traffic source, I suppose...

Comment: There's a section for traffic source too. Scroll down, or maybe select it from a drop down. Don't remember exactly.

Comment: Ah, It was curious about this meself.  That's awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Mark Mayo already answered the source of the traffic and give an explanation where the people that visited the question came from.

But in order to attract more users to this site, it would also be important to determine why this question was kind of viral in Twitter. If we know that, we could "generate" more such questions and attract more visitors.

In my opinion it has to be a mixture of topic-related but also a little bit funny off-topic. The title has to make the people curious so that the will wonder how this can be a travel related question. Additionally it has to be a topic that is well known by everybody so that it will generate a lot of potential answers. It does not have to require specific knowledge.

So it would be great if we can find more questions of this kind.